# how to access buttons that are include in Preferences android

Tags: android

I figured out that I can add buttons in this way :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
<EditTextPreference android:persistent="true" android:title="@string/username" android:key="Username"></EditTextPreference>
    <EditTextPreference android:title="@string/password" android:persistent="true" android:password="true" android:key="Password"></EditTextPreference>
    <Preference android:layout="@layout/layoutButtons" android:key="loginButtons"></Preference></PreferenceScreen>
```

and the layout file (layoutButtons.xml) :-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="10" 
android:baselineAligned="false" android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button android:text="Login" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="5" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/loginButton" android:layout_gravity="left"></Button>
<Button android:text="Password?" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="5" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/forgottenPasswordButton"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

The buttons appear but I can't access them in PreferenceActivity. I tried findViewById() but this is returning null. How can I access these buttons?

Comment: just a typo in the post or did you set `@layout/loginButtons` in your `Preference` but the resource is named `layoutButtons`  ??

Comment: oh sorry but i change now and how we get login button and password button id in PreferenceActivity